YouTube API Refresh Token Gives Invalid Format
I am creating a small php script to add some videos to a YouTube playlist, the part of getting an access token and adding the videos is working without an issue, but once the access token expires I am unable to get a new one using the refresh token, the fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken() always returns an exception 'Invalid token format'
The original acccess token is this one:
{"access_token":"ya29.a0Ad52N38HS-GI6Sh0sdfsdfB70aU815np3b9PlnD4n7BOxrjXnJpf_rxVPWsdfdsf3UMW3bWuUHfmKn9BDxz6ob592LiByk2jeUYOdnRVKb6rC1CKDkKQMy1fSbq8sdfsdfNYBJDsEeKZEHlHgaWsfsdfQVEf4FY2oQaCgYKAdMSARESFQHGX2MigIIWK5RkOe8krHadR_K3hQ0173","expires_in":3599,"scope":"https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/youtube","token_type":"Bearer","created":1712552401,"refresh_token":"1\/\/09HLLzFdZusdfsdfAAGAkSNwF-L9IrWLZCMaBh9G-uedsdfdsfkl6SG8S9OEpvm_2r3USiaOsdfdfuZWruUXSb9YA3YA"}
And I am saving it inside:
$accessTokenFilePath    = "Library/accessToken.txt";
Then the code goes as follows:
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('YouTube Parser');
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_YouTube::YOUTUBE);
$client->setClientId('client_id_goes_here');
$client->setClientSecret('client_secret_goes_here');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');

$accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($accessTokenFilePath), true);

$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
   try {
     $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($accessToken['refresh_token']);
     $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
   } catch (Exception $e) { // It always gives an exception invalid token format
     echo " Caught Exception: " . $e->getMessage();echo "\r\n";
   }
}

I tried saving the refresh token in a variable then passing this variable to the fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken() method, I also tried to save the refresh token in its own file and read it from the file, but nothing is working !

Pretty sure that $client->setAccessToken wants the token value only, not your complete JSON. $client->setAccessToken($accessToken['access_token‘]);

Inside the file Library/accessToken.txt I am not saving the whole access token, I am only saving this part: ya29.a0Ad52N38HS-GI6Sh0sdfsdfB70aU815np3b9PlnD4n7BOxrjXnJpf_rxVPWsdfdsf3UMW3bWuUHfmKn9BDxz6ob592LiByk2jeUYOdnRVKb6rC1CKDkKQMy1fSbq8sdfsdfNYBJDsEeKZEHlHgaWsfsdfQVEf4FY2oQaCgYKAdMSARESFQHGX2MigIIWK5RkOe8krHadR_K3hQ0173

I also tried now saving the whole token array with both access_token and refresh_token in a single file, and then used $client->setAccessToken($accessToken['access_token‘]); instead of $client->setAccessToken but it still gives the same exception!

"Inside the file Library/accessToken.txt I am not saving the whole access token" - if that is the case, why are you using json_decode later on in your code? That would mean that you're storing a JSON string in your *.txt file. Or am I misunderstanding your setup?

Which part of the message of the exception is unclear to you? What puzzles you most?

Thanks to all of your comments, I was able to figure the issue or rather the issues in my code as it seems a few things were not in the correct place, I have now another problem as it seems the API is returning invalid_grant, I still need to do some investigations around this error, it seems related to some configuration on Google Console or perhaps change the app to PROD but this requires a review, anyway I still need to do my investigations first
Thanks again, you were all very helpful
